# How is this C++ expression evaluated?

Tags: c++

I came across this piece of code in Leetcode and was wondering how this works. I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/conditional-operator-q?view=vs-2019) that Conditional expressions have right-to-left associativity, so shouldn't the order of evaluation be from right to left in which case it cause exception first if the stacks s1 and s2 are initially was empty?

```
stack<TreeNode*> &s = s1.empty() ? s2 : s2.empty() ? s1 : s1.top()->val < s2.top()->val ? s1 : s2;
```

Comment: Associativity != order of evaluation...

Comment: I did not imply that. But a right-to-left associativity does not mean a right-to-left *execution*. `s1.empty()` is evaluated *first*, and depending on the result, the left or right part of the `:` is evaluated next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is *grouped* as

```
s1.empty() ? s2 : (s2.empty() ? s1 : ((s1.top()->val < s2.top()->val) ? s1 : s2))
```

(Note that this is the grouping for C, C++, C#, and Java. PHP have it the other way round!)

In terms of *evaluation*, `?` acts as a *sequencing point*, and only one of the ternary conditional branches is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but comments don't support formatting code. This code shouldn't be written as a one-liner; it can be made much more clear with better formatting.

```
stack<TreeNode*> &s = s1.empty() ? s2
    : s2.empty() ? s1
    : s1.top()->val < s2.top()->val ? s1
    : s2;
```